# If a curve has velocity and acceleration of constant magnitude, then its curvature is constant.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

If a curve has velocity and acceleration of constant magnitude, then its curvature is constant.

I think it's too easy a problem, but I'm not sure my solution is correct:
Let $\alpha (t) = (x (t), y (t)) $ be the curve, having constant velocity and acceleration implies that $ x' (t) = c_1 $, $ y' (t) = c_2 $, $ x'' (t) = c_3 $, $ y'' (t) = c_4 $.

Using the following equation for curvature in which the parametrization does not matter and assuming that the curve is regular:

$$
\kappa=\dfrac{x'y''-x''y'}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\dfrac{c_1c_4-c_3c_2}{(c_1^2+c_2^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
$$

So with this we conclude that the curvature is constant since the denominator is different from 0.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: The statement is that the velocity and acceleration are of constant *magnitude* (ie, their *directions* can change), but you're setting them to be constants overall, so you're only considering a subcase of the initial statement. (Also, if the velocity is constant, the acceleration is *zero*)

Comment: $\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}$ and $\sqrt{c_3^2+c_4^2}$ are constants. Not $c_i$'s themselves.

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't understand the exercise.  To solve it, would you have to solve the system of differential equations?  Could you give me a hint on how to solve it?  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which works for curves

$\alpha(t) \in \Bbb R^n \tag 1$

for any $n \in \Bbb N$, $n \ge 2$:

We have the velocity of $\alpha(t)$:

$\alpha'(t) = \dfrac{d\alpha(t)}{dt} = \dfrac{ds}{dt}\dfrac{d\alpha(t)}{ds} = \dfrac{ds}{dt}T(t), \tag 2$

$T$ being the unit tangent vector, $\vert T \vert = 1$, whence the acceleration,

$\alpha''(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left (\dfrac{ds}{dt}T(t) \right ) = \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} T(t) + \dfrac{ds}{dt} \dfrac{dT}{dt}$
$= \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} T(t) + \dfrac{ds}{dt} \dfrac{ds}{dt} \dfrac{dT}{ds} = \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} T(t) + \left (\dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^2 \dfrac{dT}{ds}; \tag 3$

the first Frenet-Serret equation (which extends to any number of dimensions $n$) reads

$\dfrac{dT}{ds} = \kappa N, \tag 4$

and thus (3) becomes

$\alpha''(t) = \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} T(t) + \left( \dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^2 \kappa N; \tag 5$

now by definition

$\dfrac{ds}{dt} = \vert \alpha'(t) \vert, \tag 6$

and we are given that $\vert \alpha'(t) \vert$ is constant, hence so is $ds/dt$, hence

$\dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{ds}{dt} = 0, \tag 7$

and thus (5) yields

$\alpha''(t) = \left( \dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^2 \kappa N; \tag 8$

taking the norm:

$\vert \alpha''(t) \vert = \left( \dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^2 \kappa \tag 9$

by virtue of the fact that

$\vert N \vert = 1; \tag{10}$

being given the hypothesis that $\vert \alpha''(t) \vert$ is constant, and having seen that so is $ds/dt$, the conclusion that $\kappa$ is constant immediately follows.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1.** Show that the angle between $\alpha''$ and $J(\alpha')= (-y',x')$ is constant. *Subhint:* For this, show that the angle between $\alpha''$ and $\alpha'$ is constant.

**Hint 2.** Note that
$$
\kappa = \frac{\alpha'' \cdot J\alpha'}{\|\alpha'\|^3}.
$$

Comment: Always love to see that good ol' $J$ put to good use! ***endorsed, +1!!!***

Comment: @Robert Lewis "Good ol' $J$...' You made me crack up, Lewis. :-) Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, good sir!